# What software can I use to create a blog/forum-like website with curated/edited video content uploaded by the users?

Tags: web-apps, video, cms, video-editing

I want to create a website that allows users to upload videos, then allows moderators to edit and trim the length of the videos as-needed to fit within the formatting guidelines. After that, one or more site editors will write an article  briefly comparing and contrasting the content of two or more related videos.

Ideally users of the site should be able to view both the original and edited versions of the video, though this isn't a hard requirement.

Does any blog, forum, or other website software currently exist which supports this workflow of crowdsourcing videos, editing them, and writing an article which has the videos embedded in it? If no website software exists, are there any hosted webapps which offer the same functionality?

I would prefer not to have users upload to YouTube because moderators wouldn't have the ability to edit the videos, and the site's content could be lost if a user's YouTube account or video is deleted.